# Set button's selected state = pressed state

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to set a button where the selected state should have the same aspect as the pressed state. The final goal of this is to allow me to after the onClick make the button stay "clicked". (or in this case, look like it)

Is there a way to override only one state with a selector?
If so, how can I override it and set it to look like the pressed state?

Comment: So ... you want a ToggleButton? http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/togglebutton.html

Comment: Yeah, I know about those but that's not really what I'm looking for.

Comment: You might want to look at their source anyway, http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.2.2_r1/android/widget/ToggleButton.java#ToggleButton